# joining tables and get count from one table in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii and I faces a small issue.In one of my project,I have two models employees and departments.In admin side,while listing the departments(grid view),I have to show the number of employees in each department.I have done the page for listing the departments but cannot able to add the number of employees in each department.

my employee table consists of :

1. empid
2. deptid
3. empname

my department table consists of:

1. deptid
2. deptname

In mysql (phpmyadmin interface) I can write a query to combine the two tables and get the correct result:

```
SELECT D. * , count( E.deptid) AS emp_count
FROM department AS D
LEFT JOIN employee AS E ON D.id = E.deptid
GROUP BY D.id
```

The result of this query:

```
id name           emp_count
1 Accounts          0
2 Development       2
3 Quality Control   1
4 Operations        0
5 Human Resources   2
6 System            1
```

How can I implement this in grid view in yii?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I'd strongly recommend that you headed over to [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and gave it a proper look, SO isn't a coding service nor a guiding / tutorial site. Please show us what you've tried and include any errors you've gotten from it

Answer (score 1):

below is the code for how to do join in cgridview,
add this code in your search function.

```
$criteria->with = array('relation_name'); 
$criteria->addCondition('relation_name.column_name ='.comparision_variable);
$model = Model::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind replay..

Will you please explain how I can get the count of employees in each department?

How I will give the condition?

Regards Biswajith kr

Answer (score 0):

add following code in above answer

```
$criteria->select = 't. * , count( employee.deptid)';
$criteria->group = 't.id';
```

first line will select the columns you needed.
Second line is for group by.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!